# Controlling the volume of a youtube video in c#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, video, youtube

i'm trying to make tool for displaying two youtube videos in two different Winform and controlling the volume with a control panel in c#.

I'm using **AxShockwaveFlashObjects** for displaying the videos.

After searching for a while, I found out it was possible with **Actionscript** and the **Flash.CallFunction()** method. But I don't know how to do it...

Here's a code I found to set the volume :

```
Flash1.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"getConfig\" returntype=\"xml\"> </invoke>");
Flash1.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"sendEvent\" returntype=\"xml\">" + " <arguments><string>volume</string><number>15</number></arguments> </invoke> ");
```

And here's for launching the video :

```
public void LaunchVideo(string link)
    {                        
        string newLink = link.Replace("watch?v=", "v/");
        newLink += "?autoplay=1";

        Flash1.Movie = newLink;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        TopMost = true;

    }
```

But even if I copy/paste the CallFunction() in my code (at the end of the LaunchVideo method), it doesn't work, I'm getting the HE

```
Consultez la fin de ce message pour plus de détails sur l'appel du débogage
juste-à-temps(JIT) à la place de cette boîte de dialogue.

************** Texte de l'exception **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Une erreur HRESULT        E_FAIL a été retournée à partir d'un appel à un composant COM.
  à ShockwaveFlashObjects.IShockwaveFlash.CallFunction(String request)
  à AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash.CallFunction(String request)
  à DxCapture.Screen1.LaunchVideo(String link) dans    C:\Users\Antoine\Desktop\Screen\DxCapture\Screen1.cs:ligne 29
  à DxCapture.Form1.button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans    C:\Users\Antoine\Desktop\Screen\DxCapture\Form1.cs:ligne 155
  à System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button,    Int32 clicks)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  à System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,    IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I assume I'm missing something important and I searched for hours but doesn't give any result so I'm asking if you guys could help me with this.

Comment: If its really that important to you maybe you should follow some **[Youtube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)** tutorials and then try for same result in your C#. This you can **[control volume](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)** using the API

Comment: Yes, it's really important for my project, thank you for your answer, I'll take a look at this. I knew it was possible with Youtube API but I didn't know how to use it with C# project. I've found something to do it so I'll try and I'll tell you if it's fixed.
Thanks again @VC.One